# IntelliJ IDEA - Scala formatting

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1 EAP
Say I have this class.

```
@Entity
case class MyEntity(
                          @Id
                          id: String,
                          title: String,
                          content: String)
```

Is it somehow possible to format it this way?

```
@Entity
case class MyEntity(
      @Id
      id: String,
      title: String,
      content: String)
```

I actually haven't found any such option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On IntelliJ IDEA, you can go to `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Scala`.

From here, you can customize multiple style settings.

For your case, on the `Wrapping and Braces` tab (section `Method declaration parameters`), just untick `Align with multiline`. You can also control indent size on `Tabs and Indents` tab.

However, **if you work with other people**, I strongly recommend you to use a plugin like [Scalafmt](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8236-scalafmt) : therefore, you could share your configuration (`.scalafmt.conf`). IMHO, the best is nevertheless to integrate the formatting directly into your build (and not only on your IDE) for more consistency across different IDEs or platforms.